# Ajax request from select form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm trying to pull a value from my database when a select value is selected. This select is also populated from the same database.

To be clear, I'm new to AJAX requests and don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. All I get is blank when a value should appear.

This is my html form:

```js
function showStock(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("stockValue").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("stockValue").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getstock.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

    <?php $link=mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "cocktails"); // Check connection if($link===f alse){ die( "ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error()); } ?>

    <script src='menu.js'></script>

    <form action="addstock.php" method="post">
        Product:
        <br>
        <select name="products" onChange="showStock(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select a product:</option>
            <?php $sql=m ysqli_query($link, "SELECT name FROM inventory ORDER BY name"); while ($row=$ sql->fetch_assoc()){ echo "
            <option value=\ "".$row[ 'name']. "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>"; } ?>
        </select>
        <br> Stock Value:
        <div id="stockValue">
            <b>0</b>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>
    <?php
        $q = intval($_GET['q']);

        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cocktails');
        if (!$con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }

        $sql="SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE name = '".$q."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        echo $row['stock'];
        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should check if the request is being processed and what is being returned, for Google Chrome you can open the Developer Tools and go to the tab 'Network' / for Firefox you can use the extension Firebug and also navigate to the tab 'Network'. Execute the action and check the request for the file 'addstock.php' and what is the content.

Comment: I've tried your code with a test Data base and it did work for me!
Inspect more so you can give us a feedback about what is the problem exactly so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Does the dropdown list display your list of DATA ?

Comment: It does @Ayyoub

Comment: http://imgur.com/1wMpSDO - This is the initial state of the page;
http://imgur.com/7QyMSz7 - This is what happens when i select an option (the value should appear where 0 was);
http://imgur.com/TiAnso4 - This is one entry of my database (clearly 'stock' has a non null value);
http://imgur.com/MfSVQ6c - This is the Network Tab in developer tools in chrome;

Comment: When you select a value, what happen in your browser' console ?

Comment: @Ayyoub the console shows nothing, but this is the Network Tab in the developer tools (http://imgur.com/MfSVQ6c)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136167/discussion-between-ayyoub-and-x3minater).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well It wasn't that evident but your problem is :

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
```

your `$_GET['q']` is a string and you are converting it to an `intval` so it becomes a `0`.

And your SQL query is getting nothing because of that.

Change this line to `$q = $_GET['q'];` and it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all HTML from your php, and all will be good I think. Your php response must be plainText here not HTML

```
    <?php
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cocktails');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    $sql="SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE name = '".$q."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo $row['stock'];
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $link=m ysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "cocktails"); // Check connection if($link===f alse){ die( "ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error()); } ?>
```

should be ..

```
<?php $link=mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "cocktails"); // Check connection if($link===f alse){ die( "ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error()); } ?>
```

Might have been a typo but the space on `mysqli_connect` will be causing ti to fail

same again here..

```
<?php $sql=m ysqli_query($link, "SELECT name FROM inventory ORDER BY name");
```

should be ..

`<?php $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name FROM inventory ORDER BY name");`

Comment: Nice eye, but it was probably a typo when pasting it here. There was no space in my code. :/